# Problem running a modified startup-script in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automation, google-compute-engine, startupscript

I am trying to set up an Instance using an Instance Template in the GCP Deployment Manager. It works fine but upon adding startup-script in metadata, it doesn't.

This is the code (and script) I am trying to run:

> gcloud compute instances create my-instance --source-instance-template my-it --zone=northamerica-northeast1-a --network=my-network --subnet=my-subnet --no-address --metadata=startup-script='sudo /opt/scripts/startup.sh
> #! /bin/bash
> sudo htpasswd -c -B -b /etc/nginx/.htpasswd test test'

Here, the following part comes from the instance template itself and I am trying to add in the latter.

> sudo /opt/scripts/startup.sh

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Assuming you are trying to deploy a VM and add a start up script from a local file > https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux#passing-local. You might want to double check the syntax ... --metadata-from-file=startup-script=sudo /opt/scripts/startup.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCP documentation says that when creating a VM from an instance template, the default behavior is to create a VM instance precisely as described in the instance template except for the instance name and zone; if you want to override an attribute, you only need to pass the new value. [Create a vm instance from an instance template with overrides](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-vm-from-instance-template#create_a_vm_instance_from_an_instance_template_with_overrides)

You can see from the documentation that **gcloud compute instance-templates** has the same **--metadata** and **--metadata-from-file** flags as **gcloud compute instances**
[gcloud compute instance-templates](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-templates/create#--metadata),[gcloud compute instance create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create)

So any new value to **--metadata** when creating a new instance with **--source-instance-template=my_template** will only override the value from the instance template (no adding). The **--metadata-from-file** flag maybe me more suitable for your use case( new .sh with the startup-script form instance template + extra steps)

Comment: That clears it up, thanks!